# Reading JVM heap bin file through java program

Tags: java, jvm

I can successfully generate take heap snapshot and save it as a binary file. Now , the problem is as I don't know the structure / format of binary heap file , I can not read it from program. I know , I can do it using jHat. But I want to do it through code.

Any pointers in this regard ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of heap snapshot is described in https://java.net/downloads/heap-snapshot/hprof-binary-format.html

Answer (score 1):

jhat sources are available in openjdk in openjdk\jdk\src\share\classes\com\sun\tools\hat\

Answer (score 0):

http://openjdk.java.net/groups/serviceability/index.html#tools

You'll need to download the OpenJDK source tree. The [repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/) will give you everything, but I find it hard to navigate. I *think* it will be easier to find the directory in the [JDK source tarball](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/) (but haven't looked; it might not be there).

Answer (score 0):

Source code of [Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) should be of great help for you